# Is there a word (or expression) for when you can see someone doing something wrong?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

Is there a word or expression that succinctly describes/conveys the following:

> I am watching someone perform a *reasonably* complex task/activity.
> I can see a person doing something wrong, I know how to do it "*right*" from years of practice/experience, but it would take me too long to explain/train them to do it the *right* way (*and they may not **want** to learn / modify their existing behaviour*), so I just let them continue without causing a "fuss", but it still "bugs me" inside.

A single word would be *awesome* (*however I expect it's unlikely*). Failing that, an *expression* or "parable" would be good, too.
*Essentially*, I just want to convey this *idea* without telling people "***you're** doing it all **wrong***"!

Comment: It seems to me that the person performing the task is on a learning curve and that the observer (standing by doing nothing) is on a teaching curve.

Comment: Nigel, that is a _reasonable_ observation. However the people in question are not especially "_teachable_" ... this image comes to mind: ![too-busy-to-improve](https://hakanforss.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/are-you-too-busy-to-improve2.png)

Comment: You are an *unrequited mentor*.

Comment: When you guys are ready, I can help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

> ... so I just let them continue
> without causing a "fuss",
> but it still "bugs me" inside.

Your situation seems like a good time to **bite your tongue**.

**bite your/one's tongue** (phrase)

> Make a desperate effort to avoid saying something.
>
> *I often felt like I had to bite my tongue and take deep breaths to avoid berating them for their complete lack of common sense or
> perspective.*
>
> *It is certainly not the kind of situation where confrontation is advisable - and that is why our seething guide bites his tongue and
> suppresses the urge to curse at their thoughtless conduct.*
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bite_one%27s_tongue)

> To stop yourself from saying something that you would really like to
> say:
>
> *I wanted to tell him exactly what I thought of him, but I had to bite my tongue.* [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bite-your-tongue)

---

> He chuckled, hauled out the ironwork, and set to work hooking up the
> printer to the laptop. He was doing it all wrong, but I **bit my tongue**.
> I'd realized long ago *the futility of telling Michael how to do
> computer tasks*, so I left him to figure it out and want back to
> selling my dusty ironwork. [Donna Andrews; *Revenge of the
> Wrought-Iron Flamingos*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Revenge_of_the_Wrought_Iron_Flamingos/eek2QxLcrXgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=was%20doing%20it%20all%20wrong%20but%20I%20bit%20my%20tongue&pg=PT176&printsec=frontcover) (2006)

> I had to **bite my tongue**. I would just have said there was a dead
> body in the woods. *It was far too complicated to explain what was
> actually happening.* For now, it just needed something to grab their
> attention, to make them respond. [Jon Wilmot; *The Trail*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Trail/JnS3BwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=was%20doing%20it%20all%20wrong%20too%20complicated%20I%20bite%20my%20tongue&pg=PA316&printsec=frontcover) (2014)

> As a teacher, it is hard to **bite your tongue** and let a reader
> continue reading when he or she makes a mistake, but *it is the only
> way* struggling readers will develop the monitoring system good readers
> already have. When a reader makes a mistake, wait until he or she
> reaches the end of the page, and then intervene. [Timothy Rasinski;
> *Rebuilding the Foundation*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Rebuilding_the_Foundation/724XBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=bite%20your%20tongue%20too%20difficult&pg=PT113&printsec=frontcover) (2011)

Comment: Had some dental work the other day and I keep biting my tongue.  I'll have to watch more closely to figure out who is screwing up.

Answer (score 1):

- A somewhat broader term you might want to use is [toe-curling](https://www.lexico.com/definition/toe-curling):

  > Very embarrassing or excessively sentimental.

  *I toe-curlingly had to watch him fumble.*
- A good alternative is **[cringeworthy](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/cringeworthy)**:

  > Causing a reaction or feeling of embarrassment, awkwardness, or discomfort.

  *His blundering was a cringeworthy affair.*